# Permission to "my_github_repository" denied to "username"

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm trying to upload my work in my github repository. The computer I'm using is shared, another student was using it with his github account, so now here is mu problem:

when I try to push to my repo this message appears:

```
$ git push https://github.com/Ruex97/Sprint-1-Tasca-3.git
remote: Permission to Ruex97/Sprint-1-Tasca-3.git denied to his_username.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Ruex97/Sprint-1-Tasca-3.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I guess if i change it to my username in git problem should be solved, but i updated user and email and still have the error. Any help?

Comment: Git does not use your `user.name` or `user.email` settings in any way to authenticate. (In fact, Git itself does not do any authentication: Git runs *other programs* to have them do authentication.) Since you're using https, you're getting whatever https credential helper you have configured.

Comment: (There are almost certainly better duplicates but I did not find them with a quick search.)